# Breaking news of applying for a department transfer to current boss

Tags: career-development, applications, developer

I have decided that I would like to be part of a new team that is being created within my current work place.

What is the kindest way to break this news to my current boss?

I have nothing against my current boss, in fact his support and guidance so far was a big factor in me not wanting to join the new team. Especially as I have not been at the company long (5 months) and he is the one that hired me.

But the fact is the new team is not only going to be working on new things (always fun) but its they are going to work on something that I already find myself very passionate about. Ultimately I think I would be happier in the new team, but this is not because I am unhappy in my current team I want to let my boss know that I will be making a formal application.

Sadly I have already got the ball rolling in some respects, I would much rather have given him a heads up beforehand but the opportunity to get the ball rolling came up and I didn't want to miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are naturally kind and honest, you'll find a way to tell him. If you aren't the kind and honest type, he'll see through whatever phoney baloney concoction of words and phrases you use on him to make him feel better - Your body language will give you away.

Make sure you offer to do everything you can to make the transition as smooth as possible and to offer to be of assistance after you make the transition to the other team. And stay in touch with him after you leave.

Don't say anything to him until you have your membership in the new team securely in hand or at least until you get the approval of the manager of the new team. If you tell him and you don't make the new team, your losing face will be the least of your worries.

Comment: I have spoken to the other manager, thats what had made me feel bad, after the fact it felt like i had done it behind my current managers back but now i realise it was just by chance really. I still have to interview for that role but before i can interview it needs to be signed off by my current boss

Comment: @chrispepper You need to review and edit part of your code of ethics because it makes absolutely no practical sense for you to be talking to your current manager without talking to the other manager first. If you had talked to your current manager and then talked to the other manager only to find out that the dream team is not what you thought it is, then you'd be in a pickle with your current manager. You are not one of thosa who change jobs by telling their company that you are quitting, then float their resumes and hope to be called for interviews, are you?

Comment: @chrispepper Personally, if after talking to the target, I estimate that the chances that they'll say "yes" are pretty good, I'd go for it.

Comment: interesting I hadn't really thought of it like "another job", I am definitely not someone who would tell a place I am quitting an then go looking! I guess I was being a tad to nice, thanks :)

Comment: @chrispepper It has nothing to do with being nice or not nice because it's not even personal. It's just business - think it again :) You already acknowledged the good things he's done for you and I presume that you'll be more than ready to do good things for him when the occasion presents itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing "unkind" about "hey, I have an opportunity that sounds really interesting;  how can we clean things up here so I don't leave anything hanging in incomplete/undocumented state?" Actually, the two managers should be coordinating exactly how and when you move over....